# Git pull without affecting local files in an infinite for loop?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have an infinite loop and doing some process inside it. Let say there is a main.properties file which is regularly used inside the infinite loop.
Now i want to pull the same main.properties file from gitlab using git pull command, but git pull command overwrite the local file with the new file (imported from gitlab). To overwrite the local file first it will delete the local file. So at this point when there is no main.properties to refer ( because local file is deleted for replacement), the infinite loop will break.

Do we have git commands so that, i can import main.properties from gitlab without deleteing the local main.properties?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to stash your changes before you pull and apply your changes after the pull. It would look something like this.

```
git stash
git pull
git stash apply
```

This would temporarily undo all changes and then reapply them after you pull. This could cause merge conflicts too if you're modifying the same file.

Comment: yes, i have the same file locally and on remote repository. How can i solve the merge conflict? Additionally, i don't understand the merge conflict clearly, can you give some examples

Comment: How would compiler will access the file (main.properties) from stash area? And when a file of same name (main.proerties) will get downloaded (after using git pull), how would it know to access/refer to which file as we have two files with same name?

Comment: Additinally, can we delete file from stash area?

Comment: I am unsure what you are trying to do. A merge conflict occurs when the same part of a file has been modified and pushed to the remote directory and then you try to pull it into your local directory. A merge conflict implies that it can't resolve itself automatically. You can force it to take either what is on the remote directory or ignore what is on the remote and only take what is on your local. It sounds like you need something from the remote so i assume you want to force the remote into your local. This will likely break things and wouldn't' be the best way to work

Comment: One question, what happens when i pull a file with same name as in local from remote. Is there any way i can keep both the files in my local dir after git pull or any other command sequence?

Comment: Git will try to add a file with the same name as the file on your local machine. It will see that a file with that name exists and it will then compare the file it's trying to download to the one that is on your local machine and see if they are from the same origin. If they share the same origin git will try to update the local file to the current form that it's in. If they are from a different origin, git will crash. If they are from the same origin but have changes git will try merge them. If the merges are conflicting you will get a merge conflict.

Comment: what do you mean by same origin? how git determines it?

Answer (score 0):

> Do we have git commands so that, i can import main.properties from gitlab without deleteing the local main.properties?

The short answer is no.

The long answer gets into what it means to *delete* a file, *create* a file, or *replace* a file; what exactly is the *identity of a file* in the first place; what does it mean to do something "simultaneously"; what sort of properties does your OS provide, if any, to allow for synchronization between otherwise-unsynchronized operations; and so on.

Your system may provide an *atomic rename operation*.  This may produce a file that has a different *identity* (inode number, or similar identity), which may or may not become apparent to this infinite-loop process.  All of this is entirely independent of Git.  You should investigate whether and how your OS can help you out here.

Git will not use fancy OS-specific mechanisms.  What this means is that if you want to atomically swap out some sort of configuration file, you should have your infinite loop run *outside the Git repository entirely*.  This allows you to do whatever you like *in* the Git repository, without worrying about what happens to your infinite-loop process.  Then, whenever it's appropriate and convenient, you use your OS-provided facilities—whatever those may be; obviously they will depend on the OS—to do any fancy work you need done.  Git will not do it for you, but you will not need Git to do it for you.